# How to use colorbox with base64 image?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, colorbox

I'm trying to use colorbox image with base64, but when I click to open the image in the slideshow, it does not open. I'm using backbone framework.

```
<!-- html code -->
<a href="<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= image %>"/>" title="<%= description %>"> 
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= image %>" alt="" />
</a>

//javascript code
this.$el.find('ul li > a').attr('rel', 'gallery').colorbox({
   maxWidth     : '80%',
   maxHeight    : '80%',
   opacity      : '0.1',
   inline       : true,
   html         : true,
   loop         : true,
   slideshow    : true,
   slideshowAuto: false,
   fixed        : true
 });
```

Comment: What's the value of: `this.$el.find('ul li > a').length` when the `colorbox` function is executed?

Comment: I hadn't noticed this, but I can't imagine that the `href` being set to an html tag (`<img src="data:image...."`) would work. The general idea of these types of JavaScript libraries is that you don't load larger images until it's necessary. The `href` attribute should have a url in it. You could look at the `onLoad` event to see if there's some manipulation you could do to make this work.

Comment: I can not use href with a url because I'm working with mobile application and the image is being written to the local database as Base64 and I need to leave the application offline.
The FileWritterAPI only works in some browsers so I can not use it to save files locally.
Is there any way I can point the href to base64 data?

Comment: I'd look at the `onLoad` ... if that doesn't seem to fit, this may not be the best library choice for your mobile application.

Comment: Hi, I managed to resolve the error with the library fancylightbox.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily use base64 images in colorbox . base64 images are preloaded images so just put a photo attribute in your colorbox initialization

```
$('a.img_box').colorbox({'photo':true});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you still want to use Colorbox instead of Fancybox the easiest solution is to lie to Colorbox and tell it it is a JPG.
Just add a "#.jpg" at the end. For example:

```
<a href="<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= image %>#.jpg"/>" title="<%= description %>">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= image %>" alt="" />
</a>
```

That should easily work.

Comment: Yep exactly. Simple, effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Problem solved with the library fancylightbox.

```
this.$el.find('ul li > a').fancybox();
```